# How to specify the fields I want with my facets

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticJS and I want to get min/max values using facets : "StatisticalFacet".

```
// javascript
var client = ejs.Request().indices('index').types('types');
client.query(ejs.MatchQuery('field', 'test');
client.facet(ejs.StatisticalFacet('exemple').field('field').doSearch();
```

I want to know how to specify to the facet that I only want the min and max results, so I can save time during the request.

EDIT: Apparently, There's no option to do that yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for the elastic.js Statistical Facet can be found at [elastic.js: Module: StatisticalFacet](http://docs.fullscale.co/elasticjs/ejs.StatisticalFacet.html) I did not see where you can specify to limit the results of the statistical facet to only the min and max results in this documentation or in the [Statistical Facet documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-statistical-facet.html) for elasticsearch itself either,

Comment: Exactly, I've already seen the documentation you mentionned (both) but as I said in the question, I can't find anything specific on the 'param' method.

Comment: According to the details for the `params` method it is to be used in conjunction with the `script` method to populate any parameters that you may be using in a script to calculate the statistical facet. The elasticsearch Statistical Facet documentation shows an example of this.

Comment: Mmmmmh, so in other words, there is absolutly no option to control whether stat you want or not, but I can add as many scripts for additionnal stats as I want ... That's weird, and frankly bit useless in my opinion. Thanks anyway, I could have searched a long time.